# Convert eps to pdf and crop white spaces

Tags: pdf, postscript, eps

I have a script that a used before and it worked. But now it does not working (I changed the machine).

to convert eps files to pds files

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Find::Rule;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
->name( '*.eps' )
->in( './' );

for my $file (@files) {
print "file: $file\n";
system("epstopdf", $file);
}
```

to crop white spaces

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Find::Rule;

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
->name( '*.pdf' )
->in( './' );

for my $file (@files) {
print "file: $file\n";
system("pdfcrop", $file, $file);
}
```

But when running the files just the names of files are written and the action is not done.
Is there something to install?

Answer (score 0):

Your Perl scripts are trying to run external programs called `epstopdf` and `pdfcrop`.